# AngularJS registering DOM elements when added from outside Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-compile

I have a scenario where I have to add DOM elements using jQuery. But the application I'm working on is developed with angular and I need those elements accessible in Angular.
Example Scenario:

```
function addElement(){
    $('body').append('<div id="outsideDiv" data-ng-click="callFn()">Added from outside angular.</div>')
}
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('someController',function($scope){
    addElement();
    $scope.callFn = function(){
      console.log("Function Called");
    }
});
```

I have a similar scenario. How can I access "#outsideDiv" and how my click function will get called?
Is there a way to make angular walk the DOM manually and register newly added elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular, the best practice is to use directives when you modify your html(with jquery etc.)

[Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

In your case I would add a directive that will be a simple element whose dom will be replaced with your new html. You can add event's, function and every thing you need via the new directive.

Comment: That is absolutely right. I will be going the directive way if I can not find a way to do the above. But the function I'm calling is in another library. And I am trying to use it as is and making modifications in my controller.

Comment: You can add a reference to the js library file(when you load your application) and use it in the directive. The onclick can call any js file you want.

Answer (score 0):

try with ng-show=somename .
when you want to show the html change it as 
    $scope.somename =  true;
when you want to hide it change as 
    $scope.somename =  false
in angular controller